# How to calculate the percent of the total per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have a query

```
SELECT
    fundingyear, tran_type, 
    COUNT(tran_type) AS total_tran
FROM
    vw_LoanRpt
GROUP by 
    fundingyear, tran_type
ORDER BY 
    FundingYear
```

It returns these results:

```
  fundingyear tran_type   total_tran
1 2017        Purchase    2501
2 2017        Refianance  3444
3 2018        Purchase    2666
4 2018        Refianance  4787
```

What I am trying to do is add a column that calculates the percentage of the total_tran per year. So that the sum of 2017's total_tran's break down the percents and same for 2018. Any help to get me on the right path is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should update your question and add  also the expected  result  .. don't post image as sample post text sample

Comment: Could you show an example of how you would get the percentage without SQL or show results as @scaisEdge has mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without a subquery:

```
SELECT fundingyear, tran_type, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_tran,
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY fundingyear) as year_ratio
FROM vw_LoanRpt
GROUP by fundingyear, tran_type
ORDER BY FundingYear;
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked out better for what I am needing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Since I dont have data I couldnt test this out but this should work (I am guessing you want the marginal contribution of `total_tran` by `tran_type` for each year):

```
    SELECT fundingyear, tran_type, total_tran, 
           (100*total_tran)/SUM(total_tran) OVER(PARTITION BY funding_year) AS total_tran_perc
    FROM
    (
    SELECT fundingyear, tran_type, COUNT(tran_type) AS total_tran
    FROM vw_LoanRpt
    GROUP by fundingyear, tran_type
    ) a1
    ORDER BY fundingyear
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. I am so new to this type of querying that it hurts sometimes.

Comment: Happy to help. Please try to be more explicit with what you want your result to look like in the future.

Comment: Btw, as Window Aggregates are calculated *after*  aggregation, this could be further simplified without Derived Table: `SELECT fundingyear, tran_type, Count(*) AS total_tran,
        (100.0*Count(*))/Sum(Count(*)) Over(PARTITION BY funding_year) AS total_tran_perc
    FROM vw_LoanRpt
    GROUP BY fundingyear, tran_type`

Comment: Indeed! Thank you.